# Getting MacOS process id from user using python

Tags: python, psutil

I want to get the pid by passing in the user name. For example, in the picture of a macOS activity monitor, the user name is 'root', and I want something that can return all running processes under user name 'root'.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [psutil.process_iter()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.process_iter) to get all running processes, and then filter them by matching [psutil.Process.username()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.username) with the desired username.

The following code shows a function that produces a list of psutil.Process objects.

```
import psutil

def pids_for_user(username: str) -> list[psutil.Process]:
    return [p for p in psutil.process_iter() if p.username() == username]

print(pids_for_user("root"))
```

Make note of all the [exceptions](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#exceptions) that may be raised when you work with processes.